# Oracle Object Type and Object Table

Tags: oracle, plsql, object-type

I have created an object type and a table. I would like to know how select, insert, update and delete operation on it.

```
create table employee_info (
  empid number,
  emp_name varchar2(50),
  department varchar2(20),
  designation varchar2(50),
  salary number
);

create type employee_info_obj is object (
  empid number,
  department varchar2(50),
  designation varchar2(50),
  salary number
);

create type employee_info_obj_t is
table of employee_info_obj ;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When inserting values into an object table in Oracle SQL, how do you declare nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72678415/when-inserting-values-into-an-object-table-in-oracle-sql-how-do-you-declare-nes)

Answer (score 1):

You have only created an object type and an unrelated database table. If you want a database table based on the type, you need to create one:

```
create table employee_info of employee_info_obj;
```

While it can be nice in certain programming scenarios to have a type synced to a table, there are some downsides such as it being harder to add columns later, and third party tool support since the object table will not be listed in `user_tables` but only in `user_object_tables` and `user_all_tables`, so I would question the usefulness of this approach.

[dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jajQ0hV1)

Comment: Actually , i am getting data from micro services , like to update department number.so how can i update. Can you further explain this.

Comment: Are you asking how to update a table?

Comment: Yes  , not only to update but also select , insert and delete as well.

Comment: `update employee_info set department = 'SALES' where empid = 1234;`

Comment: i think you didn't understand from above. I need to update through object table.

Comment: In my example and in my dbfiddle, `employee_info` is an object table, and that is how you update it, so I am not sure what else you are looking for.